# A Maths exercise from school I couldn't solve with a system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, puzzle

Three players decide to play a game where the loser doubles the amount of money every other player has. They play three rounds and every player loses once. In the end after 3 rounds each one of them has 40 euros in their pockets.

Tell me the initial money each one of them had!

> I experimented with some equations like x + y + z = 120 and 4(x-y-z)=40 and 2(2y-(x-y-z)) = 40 and 4z-2(2y-(x-y--z))-4(x-y-z)=40 (You know doing the process with the variables for each variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume they all started with unknown amounts:

$$x, y, z$$
After round one:
$$x - y - z, 2y, 2z$$
After round two:
$$2(x - y - z), 3y - x - z, 4z$$
After round three:
$$4(x - y - z), 6y - 2x - 2z, 7z - x - y$$
Solving this system of equations, gives:
$$x = 65,\ y = 35,\ z = 20$$

Comment: Should not be there some money taken from the losers?

Comment: Generally in a game the total money people play with in the beginning equals the total amount of money people leave with after the game is over. This would make the problem more interesting.

Comment: @Med - revised my answer

Comment: Thanks! Almost got that alone but did something wrong at the third round. Should have made a grid on the sheet of paper to make it easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

Work backwards: At the end of game 3, the players have
$$
40, 40, 40
$$
Assuming player 3 lost game 3, then the start of game 3 saw:
$$
20, 20, 80
$$
Assuming player 2 lost game 2, then the start of game 2 saw:
$$
10, 70, 40
$$
So player 1 lost game 1, which means the start of game 1 saw:
$$
65, 35, 20
$$

Comment: A much better solution than mine.

Comment: no @nbubis i needed exactly those equations: 4(x-y-z) = 40, 6y-2x-2z = 40 7z-x-y = 40 and x+y+z = 120 to get the initial money everyone had. Its what I have to give as an answer because were taking a look on the systems of equations

Answer (score 1):

You can just reverse the game:
At the end they each have 40:
$$40,40,40$$

Before the third run: $$20, 20, 40+20+20=80$$
or $$20,20,80$$

Before the second run

$$10,20+10+40,40$$
or
$$10,70,40$$
And initially
$$10+35+20,35,20$$
or $$65,35,20$$